# Application UI is completely distorted when Mobile Phone Display Text Size is enlarged - Not Responsive

Tags: flutter, fonts, flutter-layout, accessibility, font-size

When the user increases the Display Font Size of mobile phone Android/iOS the application UI is completed broken.

Requirement: I need to fix the size of all the TextFields though the user increases the display font size. (Give no support for Accessibility)
Note: I have already given "fontSize" to my textfields, though it enlarges when font size is increase.

Steps to reproduce it:
iOS Mobile: Settings -> Accessibilities -> Display and Text Size -> Large Text -> On -> Maximum
Android Mobile: Settings -> Display -> Font Size -> Huge

Please let me know if any solution prevails.
Help will be appreciated.

Here is my flutter doctor -v

Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on macOS 11.2.1 20D74 darwin-arm, locale en-IN)
• Flutter version 1.22.6 at /Users/sunflower/Documents/flutter
• Framework revision 9b2d32b (3 months ago), 2021-01-22 14:36:39 -0800
• Engine revision 2f0af37152
• Dart version 2.10.5

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
• Android SDK at /Users/sunflower/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
• ANDROID_HOME = /Users/sunflower/Library/Android/sdk
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.4)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
• CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin installed
• Dart plugin version 201.9317
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

Please find the attached files to get the highlight of the issue.

[When Font Size is increased Application UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tD7da.png)
[Everything is overflowed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yl4a6.png)

Answer (score 0):

this might help, [font size change prohibited](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19707),

```
MaterialApp(
builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
return MediaQuery(
data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: textScaleFactor),
child: child,
);
},
title: 'Home Page',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lock the `textScaleFactor` to `1.0` in your 'MaterialApp`:

```
 MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget _) {
        return MediaQuery(
          data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0), // like this
          child: Home(), // Your widgets go here
        );
      },
    );
```